# How to evaluate $ \:\sum _{n=3}^{\infty \:}\frac{4n^2-1}{n!}\:\: $?

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

I am trying to evaluate:

$$ \:\sum _{n=3}^{\infty \:}\:\:\frac{4n^2-1}{n!}\:\: \quad (1)$$

---

My attempt:

$$ \:\sum _{n=3}^{\infty \:}\:\:\frac{4n^2-1}{n!}\:\: \quad  = 4\sum _{n=0}^{\infty \:} \frac{(n+3)^2}{(n+3)!} + \sum _{n=0}^{\infty \:} \frac{1}{(n+3)!}$$

The last form is very similar to the expotential series, but I can't get it from here.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Hint:
$$
\frac{k^2}{k!} = \frac{k-1+1}{(k-1)!} = \frac{1}{(k-2)!} + \frac{1}{(k-1)!}
$$

Comment: but how to calculate  $$ \sum _{k=3}^{\infty} \frac{1}{(k-2)!} $$ and  $$ \sum _{k=3}^{\infty} \frac{1}{(k-1)!} $$? The exponential series is  $$ \sum _{k=0}^{\infty} \frac{1}{k!} $$

Comment: $$\sum_{k=3}^\infty\frac1{(k-1)!}=\sum_{k=2}^\infty\frac1{k!}=e-2.$$

Answer (score 3):

Note that  $$e= \sum _{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n!}$$
\begin{split}
\sum _{n=3}^{\infty }\frac{4n^2-1}{n!}  &= 4\sum _{n=3}^{\infty }\frac{n^2}{n!} -\sum _{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n!}+\frac{5}{2}\\
&=4\sum _{n=3}^{\infty }\frac{n-1+1}{(n-1)!} -\sum _{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n!}+\frac{5}{2}\\
&= 4\sum _{n=3}^{\infty }\frac{1}{(n-1)!} + 4\sum _{n=3}^{\infty }\frac{1}{(n-2)!} -\sum _{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n!}+\frac{5}{2}\\
&= \frac{5}{2}+4\sum _{j=2}^{\infty \:}\:\:\frac{1}{j!} + 4\sum _{k=1}^{\infty }\frac{1}{k!} -\sum _{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n!} \\
&= \frac{5}{2}+4(e-2)+ 4(e-1)-e=7e-\frac{19}{2}
\end{split}

Answer (score 3):

For higher powers (series of the form $\displaystyle  \sum_{k\geq 0}\frac{k^n}{k!} , n > 0 $ ) we use [Dobínski's formula](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dobi%C5%84ski%27s_formula)  and the our problem is just particular case of it.
.

$$4\sum_{n\geq 3}\frac{n^2}{n!}-\sum_{n\geq 3}\frac{1}{n!}=4\left(\sum_{n\geq 0}\frac{n^2}{n!} -1-\frac{2^2}{2!}\right)-\left(\sum_{n\geq 0}\frac{1}{n!}-2-\frac{1}{2!}\right)=4\sum_{n\geq 0}\left(\frac{n^2}{n!}-\frac{1}{n!}\right)-12+\frac{5}{2}$$ and hence by [Dobiński's formula](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dobi%C5%84ski%27s_formula) we have $$4eB_2-eB_0-\frac{19}{2}= 8e-e-\frac{19}{2}=7e -\frac{19}{2} $$ where $B_n$ is *nth Bell number* with $B_0=B_1=1$ and $B_2=2$

Comment: Note: I think it is $e - \frac{17}{2}$

Comment: @Veriun, you can verify the answer [here](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sum+k%3D3+k%3D+infinite++%284k%5E2-1%29%2F%28k%21%29) with wolfram alpha , which is $7e-19/2$.